# Testing STDOUT output in Rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec2

I am trying to build a spec for this statement. It is easy with 'puts'

```
print "'#{@file}' doesn't exist: Create Empty File (y/n)?"
```

Answer (score 102):

#### RSpec 3.0+

RSpec 3.0 [added a new `output` matcher](http://rspec.info/blog/2014/05/notable-changes-in-rspec-3/#new-output-matcher) for this purpose:

```
expect { my_method }.to output("my message").to_stdout
expect { my_method }.to output("my error").to_stderr
```

#### Minitest

Minitest also has something called [`capture_io`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/minitest/5.0.6/Minitest/Assertions#capture_io-instance_method):

```
out, err = capture_io do
  my_method
end

assert_equals "my message", out
assert_equals "my error", err
```

#### RSpec < 3.0 (and others)

For RSpec < 3.0 and other frameworks, you can use the following helper. This will allow you to capture whatever is sent to stdout and stderr, respectively:

```
require 'stringio'

def capture_stdout(&blk)
  old = $stdout
  $stdout = fake = StringIO.new
  blk.call
  fake.string
ensure
  $stdout = old
end

def capture_stderr(&blk)
  old = $stderr
  $stderr = fake = StringIO.new
  blk.call
  fake.string
ensure
  $stderr = old
end
```

Now, when you have a method that should print something to the console

```
def my_method
  # ...
  print "my message"
end
```

you can write a spec like this:

```
it 'should print "my message"' do
  printed = capture_stdout do
    my_method # do your actual method call
  end

  printed.should eq("my message")
end
```

Comment: Where should the `def capture_stdout &block` code go?  In the spec file?

Comment: You can put it in a separate spec helper file and then include that file whenever you need it

Comment: @p11y: It works like a charm, thanks. One small correction though, the it block should have a `do`, I couldn't edit the answer since the edit must be atleast 6 characters

Comment: Is that &blk a proc?

Comment: @Jwan622 yes, `&blk` is a proc that contains the computations in the `do ..end` block passed to the method.

Comment: `$stdout = fake = StringIO.new` does not work for me, I have use `$stdout.reopen("out.txt", "w")`

Comment: Note that RSpec output matcher also has `output.to_stdout_from_any_process`. Ruby's `Logger` for example cannot be tested with simply `to_stdout`.

Comment: This solution works, but if you have multiple tests with different stdout output, the output from the first test interfere with the one from the second.

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
The alternative solution for Rspec totally works.

Answer (score 3):

If your goal is only to be able to test this method, I would do it like this:

```
class Executable
  def initialize(outstream, instream, file)
    @outstream, @instream, @file = outstream, instream, file
  end

  def prompt_create_file
    @outstream.print "'#{@file}' doesn't exist: Create Empty File (y/n)?"
  end
end


# when executing for real, you would do something like
# Executable.new $stdout, $stdin, ARGV[0]

# when testing, you would do
describe 'Executable' do
  before { @input = '' }
  let(:instream)   { StringIO.new @input }
  let(:outstream)  { StringIO.new }
  let(:filename)   { File.expand_path '../testfile', __FILE__ }
  let(:executable) { Executable.new outstream, instream, filename }

  specify 'prompt_create_file prompts the user to create a new file' do
    executable.prompt_create_file
    outstream.string.should include "Create Empty File (y/n)"
  end
end
```

However, I want to point out that I would not test a method like this directly. Instead, I'd test the code that uses it. I was talking with a potential apprentice yesterday, and he was doing something very similar, so I sat down with him, and we reimplemented a portion of the class, you can see that [here](https://gist.github.com/JoshCheek/5561023).

I also have a [blog](http://archive.today/LKajj) that talks about this kind of thing.