# Testing with RSpec - Output activity messages to STDOUT in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rspec, tdd, stdout

I'm looking for some help outputting the activity messages into the command line window. I know this may seem backwards but this is the task I've been given. I've already written tests so that they all pass but I need to convert the below activity into the command line window. It's just a game that resembles the Impossible Machine game.

Firstly I need to create a process which starts the Impossible Machine, then simulate each of the activities being initiated in succession before finishing.

Of what I understand, all the messages displayed should be sent to the STDOUT channel. These are some of the tests that have been written:

```
module ImpossibleMachine
# Input and output constants processed by subprocesses
DOWN_ARROW = 1
UP_ARROW = 2
RIGHT_ARROW = 3
REPEAT_ARROW = 4
END_PROCESS = 5 
START_CURRENT = 6

# RSpec Tests 
describe Game do
    describe "#start The impossible machine game" do
        before(:each) do
            @process = []
            @output = double('output').as_null_object
            @game = Game.new(@output)
        end
        it "sends a welcome message" do
            @output.should_receive(:puts).with('Welcome to the Impossible Machine!')
            @game.start
        end
        it "should contain a method created_by which returns the students name" do
            myname = @game.created_by
            myname.should == "My Name"
        end
        it "should perform lifts_lever_turns_wheel activity which returns REPEAT_ARROW" do
            @output.should_receive(:puts).with("Input: #{UP_ARROW}, Activity: Heave_ho_squeek_squeek")
            @process[1] = @game.lifts_lever_turns_wheel(UP_ARROW)
            @process[1].should == REPEAT_ARROW
        end
        it "sends a finishing message" do
            @output.should_receive(:puts).with('...Game finished.')
            @game.finish            
        end
    end
end
```

My only knowledge is that I need to start the module like this and then proceed to add code below it so that it outputs the activity messages to the command line:

```
module ImpossibleMachine
@process = []
g = Game.new(STDOUT)
```

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Testing STDOUT output in Rspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507067/testing-stdout-output-in-rspec)

Answer (score 1):

It is not very clear from your question - you want the game to show its output to `STDOUT` when you run the rspec?

If this is the case, I'll explain why in your code as you post it, it does not happen:

When you create the new game `@game` you create it with `Game.new(@output)`. The `@output` is a `double`, which means that it is not really an output object at all, but it is a mock object instead.

This is totally fine, by the way. The only problem with it is that it doesn't *actually* print anything to the console.

If you want to make the tests, while actually printing to the console, you should pass the actual `STDOUT` object:

```
before(:each) do
  @process = []
  @output = STDOUT
  @game = Game.new(@output)
end
```

This will *almost* work, as it will print all messages *except* the ones you stub in your tests `@output.should_receive(...)`. To make those work, you should add [`and_call_original`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-0/docs/message-expectations/calling-the-original-method) to each expectation:

```
@output.should_receive(:puts).with('Welcome to the Impossible Machine!').and_call_original
```

Comment: Thanks but not quite, I want the game to run the output to STDOUT when run you run a new ruby file. I know that ruby file begins with the 3 lines of code above but I do not know what comes below that. So in other words, I need to create some new lines of code below those 3 lines that will create a process which starts the Impossible Machine, then simulate each of the activities being initiated in succession before finishing. But I do not know where to start...

Comment: Hard as I might, I can't seem to understand what exactly you need. What file? Which process? I don't know what is _in_ the `Game` class or what does `@process` do...

Comment: Don't worry, I've fixed it now. What I needed was to output the messages in a process like: @process(0) = g.lifts_lever_turns_wheel(2) etc. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without doubles:

```
  it "should perform lifts_lever_turns_wheel activity which returns REPEAT_ARROW" do
    expect(STDOUT).to receive(:puts).with("Input: #{UP_ARROW}, Activity: Heave_ho_squeek_squeek")
    @process[1] = @game.lifts_lever_turns_wheel(UP_ARROW)
    @process[1].should == REPEAT_ARROW
  end
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you revived two dead questions to give this answer, but RSpec also has a built-in matcher for this now. So you don't need doubles. https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/output-matcher

Comment: Why? To share another solution to this question, of course. Thanks for teaching me about the `output` matcher, @TonyArra. I'll add that as yet-another-solution to both these old questions.