# Capturing STDOUT in RSpec

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I'm new to unit testing in Ruby and I'm having some trouble creating a spec that will check for STDOUT. I know how to test STDOUT if the code I'm testing is within a Class/Method, but I want to just test a `puts` statement coming from a regular Ruby file that's not within a Class or Method.

Here is the simple one liner from `my_file.rb`

```
puts "Welcome to the Book Club!"
```

Here's the spec

`my_spec.rb`

```
require_relative 'my_file.rb'

  describe "Something I'm Testing" do
    it 'should print Welcome to the Book Club!' do

        expect {$stdout}.to output("Welcome to the Book Club!\n").to_stdout

      end
    end
```

I get the following error message:

```
Failures:

  1) Something I'm Testing should print Welcome to the Book Club!
     Failure/Error: expect {$stdout}.to output("Welcome to the Book Club!\n").to_stdout

       expected block to output "Welcome to the Book Club!\n" to stdout, but output nothing
       Diff:
       @@ -1,2 +1 @@
       -Welcome to the Book Club!
       # ./spec/my_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.01663 seconds (files took 0.08195 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/my_spec.rb:7 # Something I'm Testing should print Welcome to the Book Club!
```

I thought I can just use `$stdout` to capture the STDOUT from `my_file.rb` but that didn't work. The output keeps saying its nothing. I found this post that speaks about capturing output via `StringIO` [Testing STDOUT output in Rspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507067/testing-stdout-output-in-rspec)

But that method didn't work for me. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `puts` method is called when you included the `my_file.rb` right at the top, before your tests have run. Include it within your test.

```
describe "Something I'm Testing" do
  it 'should print Welcome to the Book Club!' do
     expect { require_relative 'my_file.rb' }.to output("Welcome to the Book Club!\n").to_stdout
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm. Will keep in mind for next time.

Comment: If @Uzbekjon answered your question, please accept his answer by clicking the check icon.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work for more information.

Comment: This solution works, but if you have multiple tests with different stdout output, the output from the first test interfere with the one from the second.