# Using RSpec to test user input with gets

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I'm new to Unit Testing using RSpec and Ruby and I have a question on how to test if my code is using the `gets` method, but without prompting for user input.

Here is the code I'm trying to test. Nothing crazy here, just a simple one liner.

my_file.rb

```
My_name = gets
```

Here's my spec.

```
require 'stringio'

def capture_name
    $stdin.gets.chomp
end

describe 'capture_name' do
    before do
        $stdin = StringIO.new("John Doe\n")
    end

    after do 
        $stdin = STDIN
    end

    it "should be 'John Doe'" do 
        expect(capture_name).to be == 'John Doe'
        require_relative 'my_file.rb'
    end
end
```

Now this spec works, but when I run the code it prompts for user input. I don't want it to do that. I want to simply test if the gets method is being called and possibly mock the user input. Not to sure how to achieve this in RSpec. In Python I would utilize [unittest.mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) is there a similar method in RSpec?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is very similar to your question on stdout ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37309874/capturing-stdout-in-rspec ) - the code in my file is run as soon as the file is loaded

Comment: Ah. So by moving `require_relative 'my_file.rb'` line beneath the `expect` it did work. How ever, this still doesn't assure that the `gets` ,method is being called. If I changed the value of `My_name` to anything else besides gets, the test still passes. I need the unit test to fail if `gets` isn't being called. I updated my code.

Comment: The right way to test this code would be to `expect(My_name).to eq("John Doe\n")` after requiring the file. However, the test will fail due to some interaction between `require_relative` and standard input. Overall, you're going down a bad path in executing code outside classes and trying to test it by requiring it in the test. I'd like to suggest a good path, but it's hard to do it for your example. What is the point of assigning `gets` to a constant in a required file anyway? Perhaps more context would help.

Comment: I'm using Unit Test to check if a user is using a function they were just shown. For example, a user just learned how to use the `gets` method and I want them to declare a variable and initialize it with `gets` and submit the answer via an online compiler. I use unit test to check if there correct (Pass/Fail). The only reason the `My_name` variable is a constant is because I need it to be global in order to access it from the spec file. I want to be able to create a Unit Test based on if the user declared a variable and initialized it with the gets method.

Comment: I suggest requiring the user to write a method and calling that method in your code. (I should have said above that executing code outside methods was going down a bad path, not outside classes.)

Comment: I found this article to be helpful. Solution here includes a solution from Myron Marston, the literal author of the book about testing with RSpec3 https://www.codewithjason.com/test-ruby-methods-involve-puts-gets/

Answer (score 9):

Here's how you could stub `gets` with your return value.

```
require 'rspec'

RSpec.describe do
  describe 'capture_name' do
    it 'returns foo as input' do
      allow($stdin).to receive(:gets).and_return('foo')
      name = $stdin.gets

      expect(name).to eq('food')
    end
  end
end

Failures:

  1)   should eq "food"
     Failure/Error: expect(name).to eq('food')

       expected: "food"
            got: "foo"

       (compared using ==)
```

To test if something is being called (such as a function) you can use `expect($stdin).to receive(:gets).with('foo')` to ensure it is being called (once) with the right args. The expectation line in this scenario has to go before `name = $stdin.gets`.

Comment: this only shows how to capture a single `gets`, what about multiple sequential `gets`?

Comment: @notacorn you cand pass multiple parameters like:
```allow($stdin).to receive(:gets).and_return('foo', 'bar', 'baz')```