# Rspec: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen -

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm trying to write a simple test for a ruby script that uses `gets` and I'm experiencing some weird behavior.

When I run the test with `rspec` it passes fine, but as soon as I run `rspec` with any flags, like `rspec -f json` or `rspec -O rand` the test will fail and give me `No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - -O`, where `-O` is whatever the flag that was run.

Stranger still is that if I run `rspec` and specify the test file like `rspec spec/gets_spec.rb`, I get a completely different error:

```
     Failure/Error: expect { require_relative '../gets' }.to output("Hello, Lena!\n").to_stdout                         
       expected block to output "Hello, Lena!\n" to stdout, but output "Hello, Describe \"gets.rb\" do!\n"
                     Diff:                                                                                                              
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@                                                                                                         
-Hello, Lena!                                                                                                           
+Hello, Describe "gets.rb" do!                                                                                                                                                                                                                
# ./spec/gets_spec.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I'm having trouble figuring out the right way to write my test so that this doesn't happen but I'm not sure what part of my code needs to change.

I'm using ruby 2.6.3

I learned about testing input from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37329190/10481804)

The script, `gets.rb`, looks like

```rb
puts "Hello, #{gets.chomp.capitalize}!"
```

My test looks like

```rb
describe "gets.rb" do
  before do
      $stdin = StringIO.new("lena")
  end

  after do 
      $stdin = STDIN
  end

  it "should output 'Hello, name!'" , points: 1 do
    allow($stdin).to receive(:gets).and_return("lena")

    expect { require_relative "../gets" }.to output("Hello, Lena!\n").to_stdout
  end
end
```

Here's the full failure message:

```
Failures:

  1) gets.rb should output 'Hello, name!'
     Failure/Error: expect { require_relative '../gets' }.to output("Hello, Lena!\n").to_stdout                        
     Errno::ENOENT: 
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - -O                                                                          
#./gets.rb:1:in `gets'                     
# ./gets.rb:1:in `gets' 
# ./gets.rb:1:in `<top (required)>' 
# ./spec/gets_spec.rb:14:in `require_relative' 
# ./spec/gets_spec.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
# ./spec/gets_spec.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Comment: Thanks for asking this question. I learned about testing scripts by name using require and about output matchers. +1

Comment: When I run  rspec spec/gets_spec.rb, I get: 
expected: ("Hello, Lena!")
got: ("Hello, Describe \"gets.rb\" do!")
I don't know why ...

Comment: Exactly @Christian. I can't imagine how `$stdin` is getting the content of the spec file. That doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use a little different approach:

```rb
describe "gets.rb" do
  it "should output 'Hello, name!'" do
    allow_any_instance_of(Object).to receive(:gets).and_return("lena")

    expect { require_relative "../gets.rb" }.to output("Hello, Lena!\n").to_stdout
  end
end
```

`allow_any_instance_of` I took from https://makandracards.com/makandra/41096-stubbing-terminal-user-input-in-rspec

> Reading user input in console applications is usually done using Kernel#gets.

The page suggests to use `Object.any_instance.stub(gets: 'user input')` but it's deprecated syntax already and I've updated it.

Comment: Wow, thanks! This definitely solves my issue. I didn't know about `allow_any_instance_of` until now. Definitely useful. +1

Comment: To be complete, I believe the stub should be
```ruby
allow_any_instance_of(Object).to receive(:gets).and_return("lena\n")
```

since `gets` always receives the newline. Tests _could_ fail if the implementations of `gets.rb` used `chop` and the input is just `"lena"`.