# Using let and expect in rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

At the moment, this code just runs my entire program and I'm not sure why. I've included:

```
 if __FILE__ == $0
     game = Game.new("Harry", "Nick")
 end
```

In my script but it still starts running the entire program. My goal is to print out the players' names using an instance method called #players. The closest I've come so far is with using let(:game), but all it did was fails the test saying it printed :game instead of the names of the players. Now I can't even get it to fail because it is just running the script.

```
require "tictactoe"

describe Game do
   describe "#players" do
       let(:game) do
            new_game = Game.new("Harry", "Nick")
            new_game.players
        end

       it "displays player names" do
            expect(game).to eq("Player 1: #{@player1}\nPlayer 2: #{@player2}")
       end
    end
end
```

The Game class that runs is included here:

```
 class Game

   def initialize(player1, player2)
      @player1 = player1
      @player2 = player2
      @rows = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

      @wins = [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], 
        [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9],
        [1, 5, 9], [3, 5, 7]

      @selected_numbers = []
      @counter = 0

   game_board
   start_player1
 end

   def players
      puts "Player 1: #{@player1}"
      puts "Player 2: #{@player2}"
   end

   def game_board
      @rows.each do |r|
      puts r.each { |c| c }.join(" ")
   end
   end

   def start_player1
      puts "#{@player1}: Please enter a number for your X to go"
      player1_input = STDIN.gets.chomp


      locate_player1_input(player1_input)
  end
```

Comment: Since we are not fortunetellers, the code that actually runs might help us to understand what’s going on. Please post `tictactoe.rb`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove calls to all functions:

```
game_board
start_player1
```

from your constructor. What you are doing currently is actually:

1. Instantiate `Game`;
2. Call `game_board` (which in turn prints out the board);
3. Call `start_player1`, which, surprisingly, starts player1’s moves.

But this won’t fix your test. In test you compare the string to the result of call to `puts`. Make methods *return* values, not *print* them, or use [`to_stdout`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16507067/testing-stdout-output-in-rspec#16507680) rspec matcher.

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work. I don't understand how I can remove those methods from the constructor and still have my program work. Like, if I get the tests to pass, the program won't work, and vice versa. Is there a way to combat this?

Comment: You should continue calling methods on created `Game` instance, like `game = Game.new`, `game.board` afterwards to show a board. `game.start_player1` to start a game itself etc. It’s a normal control flow, that should be implemented: `if __FILE__ == $0 ; game = Game.new("Harry", "Nick") ; game.board ; game.start_player1 ; ... ; end`